# `canvas.getContext('2d')` returns `Object` instead of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

Using 2.1.1 with Karma and Jasmine, I get a `TypeError` with this code:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(...) // TypeError here for Phantom
```

Chrome 47 and Firefox 43 are returning a `context` of type `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

[Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14115)

Comment: What exactly did you put in the argumanets of (...)

Comment: I'm rendering a created `<video>`, however it doesn't seem to matter in this case.

Comment: maybe it's the name of the variable that is being used somewhere else, how about naming it "the_canvas_aaaaa" instead of "canvas"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're running that code outside of the context of a web page.

The following snippet should work

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log('The web page said: ' + msg);
};

page.open('http://phantomjs.org/', function(status) {
    page.evaluateJavaScript(function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        console.log(canvas);
        console.log(context);
        console.log(typeof context.drawImage);
    });
    phantom.exit();
});
```

The output when running this script in PhantomJS is;

```
The web page said: [object HTMLCanvasElement]
The web page said: [object CanvasRenderingContext2D]
The web page said: function
```